# iTunes Connect : i386 libMonoPosixHelper.dylib

Tags: app-store-connect, visual-studio-mac

When I try to upload the .macOS app of a xamarin.forms Cross-Platform solution to iTunes Connect (Apple macOS App Store), I get this message:

```
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/x9/kkvymd5s6zx2f8rhzjxfrxpr0000gn/T/0BA86806-D2FE-446C-AA50-CE4A9411D9A1/1335347427.itmsp - Error Messages:
        description length:132696
        ERROR ITMS-90240: "Unsupported Architectures. Your executable contained the following disallowed architectures: '[i386 (in dk.eksit.TimeDateCalculator-macOS.pkg/Payload/timeDateCalculator.macOS.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib)]'. New apps submitted to the Mac App Store must support 64-bit starting January 2018, and Mac app updates and existing apps must support 64-bit starting June 2018.
```

What can I do to solve that problem?

(It is Visual Studio for Mac version 7.3.3 I'm using)

Comment: Are there any updates yet to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the latest Visual Studio for Mac beta

See: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120368/itunes-connect-i386-libmonoposixhelper-dylib-must-be-64-bit-starting-january-2018